# Sintaxis de función de pausa JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una página que automáticamente carga modificaciones cada 2 segundos y dentro tiene un buscador que al escribir para un `setInterval` para que mantenga la búsqueda.

En principio funciona todo con este código:

```
//refrescador del buscador
setTimeout(function(){ 
    $(".resultados_Inarticulos").load("Paginas/Articulos.php"); 
}, 10); //lo ejecuto nada mas entrar

var Pausado_Inarticulo = false;
var tiempo_Inarticulos = window.setInterval(function() {
    if(!Pausado_Inarticulo) { 
        $(".resultados_Inarticulos").load("Paginas/Articulos.php"); 
    } 
}, 2000);

$("#buscador_Inarticulos").keyup(function(){
    if ($('#buscador_Inarticulos').val() != null && $('#buscador_Inarticulos').val() != '') { 
        Pausado_Inarticulo = true; 
    } else { 
        Pausado_Inarticulo = false; 
    } 
}); //si esta vacio el buscador paro el refresco, sino sigo refrescando
//fin de refrescador del buscador
```

El caso es que quiero globalizar esa función para no tener que escribirla en cada una de las páginas y pasarla a una página de funciones comunes para todas. Para ello solo tengo que poder cambiar `Pausado_Inarticulo` por `Pausado_XXX` y quisiera poner en cada una de las páginas que quiero que funcione algo tipo:

```
Pausar('Inarticulos');
```

Y que esto llame a una función genérica que simplemente pasándole el dato de Inarticulos lo ejecute en la página Inarticulos.

¿Qué sintaxis tengo que usar? He probado a poner en la página de funciones esto, pero nada:

```
function Pausar(pagina,div,url) { 

    //refrescador del buscador
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $("."+div).load("Paginas/"+url); 
    }, 10); //lo ejecuto nada mas entrar

    var Pausado_+pagina = false;
    var tiempo_+pagina = window.setInterval(function() {
        if(!Pausado_+pagina) { 
            $("."+div).load("Paginas/"+url); 
        } 
    }, 2000);

    $("#buscador_"+pagina).keyup(function(){
        if ($('#buscador_'+pagina).val() != null && $('#buscador_'+pagina).val() != '') { 
            Pausado_+pagina = true; 
        } else { 
            Pausado_+pagina = false; 
        } 
    }); //si esta vacio el buscador paro el refresco, sino sigo refrescando
    //fin de refrescador del buscador

};
```

Pero no va y me da un error de sintaxis en la variable `var Pausado_+pagina = false;`, así que deduzco que esa forma de construir esa variable está mal.

Necesito que esa variable no tenga un nombre común ya que la página carga dentro de la propia página las distintas subpáginas a la vez con lo que no puedo llamar a las variables con el mismo nombre o afectara a todas a la vez. Tengo que poder diferenciarla de alguna forma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recibes un error porque `+` no es un carácter que se pueda usar en el nombre de una variable, ni tampoco de manera dinámica para crear un nombre al vuelo (como intentas).

Lo que sí podrías hacer es usar esa variable (que supongo contiene un identificador único de página) como índice en un **array asociativo** (simplificando: los índices serán cadenas en lugar de números). En ese caso sí que podrías generalizar la creación de variables para cada página. Por ejemplo, para la página "abc", harías `Pausado["abc"]` y `tiempos["abc"]`; para "xyz" sería `Pausado["xyz"]`, etc.

Entonces podrías hacer algo como esto:

> Nota: no lo he probado y puede contener errores, es para que veas la idea general

```
// tu variable con los manejadores de setInterval y Pausados (vacíos por defecto) 
var tiempos = [];
var Pausado = [];

function Pausar(pagina,div,url) { 

    //refrescador del buscador
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $("."+div).load("Paginas/"+url); 
    }, 10); //lo ejecuto nada mas entrar

    Pausado[pagina] = false;
    tiempos[pagina] = window.setInterval(function() {
        if(!Pausado[pagina]) { 
            $("."+div).load("Paginas/"+url); 
        } 
    }, 2000);

    $("#buscador_"+pagina).keyup(function(){
        if ($('#buscador_'+pagina).val() != null && $('#buscador_'+pagina).val() != '') { 
            Pausado[pagina] = true; 
        } else { 
            Pausado[pagina] = false; 
        } 
    }); //si esta vacio el buscador paro el refresco, sino sigo refrescando
    //fin de refrescador del buscador

};
```

Comment: Eso es exactamente lo que necesito . pero al declarar la variable var Pausado[pagina] = false; da este error SyntaxError: Unexpected token '['. Expected ';' after variable declaration.

Comment: @Killpe he actualizado la respuesta. `var` no hace falta ahí porque ya se declaró la variable previamente. Quítalo y prueba de nuevo

Comment: Eso era :) @alvaromontoro Mil gracias, funciona perfectamente